# \multicolumn in a booktabs table

Tags: multicolumn, booktabs

I'm having a few problems with a table which uses `\multicolumn` and the `booktabs` package.

This is what I've done:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{sg}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{du}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{pl}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    & \textsc{m} & \textsc{n} & \textsc{m} & \textsc{n} & \textsc{m} &
\textsc{n} \\
    \midrule
    \textsc{nom} & \textit{s} & \textit{m} \\
    \textsc{acc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{m}} \\
    \textsc{ins} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{ena}} \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textsc{dat}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{aya}} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{\={a}ya}} \\
    \textsc{abl} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{t} (\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{\={a}})} \\
    \textsc{gen} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{sya}} \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textsc{loc}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{i}} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{e}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think it's pretty clear that the horizontal centring is off where I've used `\multicolumn`. The M and N beneath SG are not equidistant from SG, the *m* in the ACC row seems to be nicely centred under SG but is woefully out of alignment with the *s* and *m* of the NOM row above.

Comment: Your third column is much larger than your second, which explains the strange-looking centering in rows 2 and 3. (The other rows are centred across columns 2 and 3. Relying on centering like this is not worth the hassle. What about something like: `c >{\centering}m{1cm} >{\centering}m{1cm} *{4}{c}}`?  As an aside: it is a bad practice (in my opinion) to kill your table rows with the `\\ ` when not all cells have been specified.

Comment: Note my earlier comment would also need to load the `array` package as in Zarko's (+1) answer....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contents in your table is still perfectly centered, however, their width is changed according to width of `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...` cells. If it is wider than your "normal" column, than additional width is added to the second column. This you can see, if you add the vertical lines to your table.

One of possible solutions is the following. Lets assume, that multicolumn cells width is not larger than `6em`. Than you can solve your problem with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\scshape}r*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{sg}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{du}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{pl}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    & \textsc{m} & \textsc{n} & \textsc{m} & \textsc{n} & \textsc{m} &
\textsc{n} \\
    \midrule
nom & \textit{s} & \textit{m} \\
acc & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{m}} \\
ins & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{ena}} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{dat} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{aya}} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{\={a}ya}} \\
abl & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{t} (\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{\={a}})} \\
gen & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{sya}} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{loc} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{i}} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{-a} $\to$ \textit{e}} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I little bit optimize your code (see difference in the first column). That code can works, I add package `array`.

[image]